# Attempting to use Comparator to sort by name, ignore case, as well as nulls first

Tags: java, comparator

I am having issues using the Java 8 Comparator class to sort a list of items.

My current working comparator is below:

```
comparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getName, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

This works: it orders the list by name with the null values first. However, I am now attempting to ignore case of the names.

I know that I can write a new getter that returns the name all lowercase, but I do not want to go with this approach as I have to do this for multiple attributes.

Looking online, it looks like I should be using `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, but the only examples I see do not include the null ordering specification.

I can do something like this:

```
comparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

However, whenever I try to include the `Comparator.nullsFirst` I end up getting type errors, and am confused on how to continue.

I've tried doing a chain similar to

```
thenComparing(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder))
```

but that also doesn't work.

Could someone lend me some advice on how I can chain these together to sort by name (not case sensitive) and then order the nulls. I seem to be confusing myself with the types.

Comment: You can very easily write your own `Comparator` instead of using the canned one. The canned ones are for the most common use cases, which clearly does not apply to you.

Comment: Can't you just wrap `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` in `Comparator.nullsFirst(...)` the same way you do with `Comparator.naturalOrder()`?

Comment: Why are you using `naturalOrder` if you are making a custom comparator BTW?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I do not want to make my own Comparator because I need to do this same sorting for many different attributes for many different objects. I would rather have one line of code that I can just change the attribute for each one.

Comment: @Bubletan looks like that did the trick! thank you

Answer (score 10):

There are two types of `null`s you can have in your list. You can have `null` `Person` references, and you can have `Person`s with `null` names.

In the first case, you have to apply [`nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) to the base comparator you want to use:

```
comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(
        Comparator.comparing(Person::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

If you have the possibility of `null` names, you need to make sure that your key never returns a `null`, or that you apply `nullsFirst` to [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER). The second option is of course much easier:

```
comparator = Comparator.comparing(
        Person::getName, Comparator.nullsFirst(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

If you have both options (`null` references *and* `null` names), you will have to combine both versions and apply `nullsFirst` twice:

```
comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(
        Comparator.comparing(
                Person::getName,
                Comparator.nullsFirst(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
        )
);
```

If you are chaining multiple comparisons like this, the outer `nullsFirst`, which ensures that `null` `Person`s get sorted properly, can be applied to the entire chain:

```
comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(
        Comparator.comparing(
                Person::getName,
                Comparator.nullsFirst(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
        ).thenComparing(...)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aweava. No problem. The language is getting more and more obfuscated as they add new features and more and more generics to everything. I appreciate the effort you put into this and understand your confusion. It's nice to be old enough to have learned java version 1.4 sometimes :)

Comment: After doing some testing these approaches seem to not be working. I get an NPE when attempting to sort any data with a null value, when before I didn't get an NPE

Comment: Just to clarify: originally my code worked when sorting it but it was case sensitive. with these approaches, it throws NPEs when nulll attributes are in the collection

Comment: @Aweava. I will look into it and fix.

Comment: Quick question. Does the list have `null` `Person` elements, or does it contain `Person`s with a `null` name? Or both?

Comment: @Aweava. I have updated my answer. I originally thought you meant that the `Person` references were `null`, but I see that you only have `null` names. I have added an explanation for both cases.